# Python - help on custom wx.Python (pyDev) class

Tags: python, wxpython, custom-controls, class-design, pydev

I have been hitting a dead end with this program. I am trying to build a class that will let me control the BIP's of a button when it is in use. so far this is what i have (see following.) It keeps running this weird error `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` - I, coming from C++ and C# (for some reason the `#include...` is so much easier) , have no idea what that means, Google is of no help so... I know I need some **real** help with syntax and such - anything would be helpful. I know there are **a lot** of questions in this I would really appreciate the help!

Note: The base code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351448/how-to-make-custom-buttons-in-wx) was used to create a skeleton for this 'custom button class'

### Custom Button

```
import wx
from wxPython.wx import *

class Custom_Button(wx.PyControl):

                                    # The BMP's
# AM I DOING THIS RIGHT? - I am trying to get empty 'global' 
# variables within the class
    Mouse_over_bmp = None #wxEmptyBitmap(1,1,1)   # When the mouse is over
    Norm_bmp = None #wxEmptyBitmap(1,1,1)         # The normal BMP
    Push_bmp = None #wxEmptyBitmap(1,1,1)         # The down BMP

    Pos_bmp = wx.Point(0,0)         # The posisition of the button

    def __init__(self, parent, NORM_BMP, PUSH_BMP, MOUSE_OVER_BMP,
                 pos, size, text="", id=-1, **kwargs):
        wx.PyControl.__init__(self,parent, id, **kwargs)

# The conversions, hereafter, were to solve another but. I don't know if it is 
# necessary to do this since the source being given to the class (in this case)
# is a BMP - is there a better way to prevent an error that i have not
# stumbled accost? 

        # Set the BMP's to the ones given in the constructor
        self.Mouse_over_bmp = wx.Bitmap(wx.Image(MOUSE_OVER_BMP, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap())
        self.Norm_bmp = wx.Bitmap(wx.Image(NORM_BMP, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap())
        self.Push_bmp = wx.Bitmap(wx.Image(PUSH_BMP, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap())
        self.Pos_bmp = self.pos

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self._onMouseDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self._onMouseUp)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self._onMouseLeave)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self._onMouseEnter)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND,self._onEraseBackground)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT,self._onPaint)

        self._mouseIn = self._mouseDown = False

    def _onMouseEnter(self, event):
        self._mouseIn = True

    def _onMouseLeave(self, event):
        self._mouseIn = False

    def _onMouseDown(self, event):
        self._mouseDown = True

    def _onMouseUp(self, event):
        self._mouseDown = False
        self.sendButtonEvent()

    def sendButtonEvent(self):
        event = wx.CommandEvent(wx.wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, self.GetId())
        event.SetInt(0)
        event.SetEventObject(self)
        self.GetEventHandler().ProcessEvent(event)

    def _onEraseBackground(self,event):
        # reduce flicker
        pass

    def _onPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
        dc.SetFont(self.GetFont())
        dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush(self.GetBackgroundColour()))
        dc.Clear()
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.Norm_bmp)

        # draw whatever you want to draw
        # draw glossy bitmaps e.g. dc.DrawBitmap
        if self._mouseIn:   # If the Mouse is over the button
            dc.DrawBitmap(self, self.Mouse_over_bmp, self.Pos_bmp, useMask=False)
        if self._mouseDown: # If the Mouse clicks the button
            dc.DrawBitmap(self, self.Push_bmp, self.Pos_bmp, useMask=False)
```

### Main.py

```
import wx
import Custom_Button
from wxPython.wx import *

ID_ABOUT = 101
ID_EXIT  = 102

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
        wxFrame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title,
                         wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(400, 400))

        self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.SetStatusText("Program testing custom button overlays")
        menu = wxMenu()
        menu.Append(ID_ABOUT, "&About", "More information about this program")
        menu.AppendSeparator()
        menu.Append(ID_EXIT, "E&xit", "Terminate the program")
        menuBar = wxMenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(menu, "&File");
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        self.Button1 = Custom_Button(self, parent, -1, 
                                "D:/Documents/Python/Normal.bmp", 
                                "D:/Documents/Python/Clicked.bmp",
                                "D:/Documents/Python/Over.bmp",
                                wx.Point(200,200), wx.Size(300,100))

        EVT_MENU(self, ID_ABOUT, self.OnAbout)
        EVT_MENU(self, ID_EXIT,  self.TimeToQuit)

    def OnAbout(self, event):
        dlg = wxMessageDialog(self, "Testing the functions of custom "
                              "buttons using pyDev and wxPython",
                              "About", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()


    def TimeToQuit(self, event):
        self.Close(true)



class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(NULL, -1, "wxPython | Buttons")
        frame.Show(true)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return true

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

### Errors (and traceback)

```
/home/wallter/python/Custom Button overlay/src/Custom_Button.py:8: DeprecationWarning: The wxPython compatibility package is no longer automatically generated or actively maintained.  Please switch to the wx package as soon as possible.
```

#### I have never been able to get this to go away whenever using wxPython  any help?

```
  from wxPython.wx import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wallter/python/Custom Button overlay/src/Main.py", line 57, in <module>
    app = MyApp(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/_core.py", line 7978, in __init__
    self._BootstrapApp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/_core.py", line 7552, in _BootstrapApp
    return _core_.PyApp__BootstrapApp(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/wallter/python/Custom Button overlay/src/Main.py", line 52, in OnInit
    frame = MyFrame(NULL, -1, "wxPython | Buttons")
  File "/home/wallter/python/Custom Button overlay/src/Main.py", line 32, in __init__
    wx.Point(200,200), wx.Size(300,100))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I have tried removing the "`wx.Point(200,200), wx.Size(300,100))`" just to have the error move up to the line above. Have I declared it right? help?

Prevous questions with this code: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990446/python-polymorphism-in-wxpython-whats-wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commented out this whole thing and the error went away and a window popped up:

```
 self.Button1 = Custom_Button(self, parent, -1, 
                              "D:/Documents/Python/Normal.bmp", 
                              "D:/Documents/Python/Clicked.bmp",
                              "D:/Documents/Python/Over.bmp",
                              wx.Point(200,200), wx.Size(300,100))
```

So getting somewhere here...

okay found the problem:

It's the import Custom_Button.  That just imports the module.  You want to use the class with the same name in that module instead so:

```
from Custom_Button import Custom_Button
```

And that problem is fixed.  You can then move on to the next error...

It was a bit hard to see the problem right away for me because you're programming in a different style than Python.  Unlike other programming languages, Python has a particular Programming Style defined in a document.  There are slight deviations from it here and there but overall most good Python developers follow it rather closely because it makes sense and helps make spotting problems easier.

[Official Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

[Google Version](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html)

Google version adds more to it and is a bit more restrictive even.

So it this case the module files should instead named custom_button.py and main.py.  The class should be named CustomButton.

Comment: what would an alternative be? I haven't been able to find another way to import the WX library.

Comment: Just import the module(s) that you are actually going to use in your program instead of everything.  Makes things easier to find - as in well where the heck did this function come from etc.

Answer (score 1):

When you import a module in Python, think of it as importing a namespace one level up in C#

For instance in C#, when you say
`import System.IO;` you can specify
`var file = new File("a.txt");`
But if you just say `import System;` you have to say
`var file = new IO.File("a.txt");`

In Python if you did the equivilent `import System.IO` you'd still need to say
`file = IO.File("a.txt")`

In order to not need to preface it in Python, you'd either need to say
`from System.IO import File` or `from System.IO import *` which is more like the C# version.

The advantage of being able to specify specific classes is when you have namespaces with lots of classes, or maybe there are conflicting class names in 2 modules you want to import.  In C# you'd either need to alias the namespace or specify the full name, where you can instead just import the specific ones you want in Python.